# Create a VolumeSnapshotContent using a snapshot handle from another GCP project?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a volume snapshot contents using a snapshot handle from another GCP project. When I create the VSC, I get this error

Failed to check and update snapshot content: failed to list snapshot for content <... name>: "rpc error: code = Internal desc = Unknown list snapshot error: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.snapshots.get' permission for '...', forbidden"

When I impersonate the service_account the cluster runs under and list or get snapshots from the other cluster, it works.

How can I create a VSC using another project snapshot in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

GCP Account need to be added on Other Project IAM first. If you are an admin and can work on other GCP resources on **Other Project** you can ask Project Owner to have an **EDITOR** Role on your account.

1. Go to IAM & Admin
2. Add Role
3. New Principal *"**Your GCP Account**"*
4. Select Role > Basic > **Editor**

For more **specific access/role** on Other Project

1. Go to IAM & Admin
2. Roles
3. Create Role
4. Add Permission > on Filter (not on dropdown) type below and add

```
compute.snapshots.create
compute.snapshots.get
compute.disks.createSnapshot
compute.image.create
compute.image.get
compute.image.delete
```

5. Go to IAM
6. New Principal *"**Your GCP Account**"*
7. Select Role > Custom Role > Search your custom role name

Also another way on **Specified Access on VM/Compute Engine Only**

1. Go to IAM & Admin
2. Add Role
3. New Principal *"**Your GCP Account**"*
4. Select Role > Add below / Add another ROle
   Compute Admin
   GKE Backup Snapshot Access
   Compute Instance Admin (v1)

Once necessary access has been created you can now create snapshot on other project.

1. Create a snapshot of the disk used by the instance.
2. Create a disk out the snapshot.
3. Create an image out the disk.
4. Swith to the other project from terminal.
5. Compute Enine > Vm Instance > Create
6. Boot Disk > Change > Custom Images > Select Other Project
7. Select Custom Image
8. Create

Comment: Hi - thanks. This is not quite what I'm looking for. I would like to avoid several of the manual steps you describe above and instead just create a vsc that references the snapshot id of a snapshot in another project directly. Then have kubernetes perform those steps (like this https://gist.github.com/leighst-anchorage/7a2791be0ae31517673712623afb8cb4). This approach works when the snapshot exists in the same project, but when the snapshot exists in another project, i get perms errors. I have tried adding those perms to the k8s service account to no avail.